# R Markdown elimination of `##` when printing data frame rows

Tags: r, r-markdown

````
---
title: "title"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE, out.width = "100%")
```

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

Each row below is preceded with `##` and I want to get rid of these preceding `##`'s. I know I can `print(mtcars, row.names = FALSE)` to get rid of the row names. But how do I get rid of the `##`? Looking into `?print()` I couldn't find any appropriate argument. My R Markdown chunk is above.

```
head(mtcars)
##                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
## Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
## Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Those are added/removed/modified via chunk options.  It's being added when the Rmarkdown is processed - not by the print function itself.

Comment: It's the `comment` argument in `opts_chunk$set`